# Change tasks list style to tree view in Inno Setup?

Tags: treeview, inno-setup

I would like to create a setup. I've make a task list. If task is checked, it will create an icon on desktop. But, I think the style of the task list is less than beautiful. I want to change it into the tree view style. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Inno Setup tasks support hierarchy/tree natively.

If you use the [tasks example code from Inno Setup documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection), and set the [`ShowTasksTreeLines` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_showtaskstreelines), you will get:

[image: Task tree]

To create a hierarchy, use task name syntax with backslashes (similarly to Windows path hierarchy):

```
[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: "Create a &desktop icon"
Name: desktopicon\common; Description: "For all users"
Name: desktopicon\user; Description: "For the current user only"
...
```